# Import CSV file into SQL Server with stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, csv, stored-procedures

I have a CSV file I would like to import into a table in SQL Server, but the table has a primary key column that I would like to be generated by a stored procedure that produces this ID as an output parameter. How would I go about doing this? I need to run the procedure for each row to get the unique id for each record imported

Comment: What have you tried?  And have you considered doing this as a SSIS package rather than a SP (may make more sense)

Comment: I have tried Import data and I've looked at some examples of using Stored procs and SQL scripts, but I can't seem to figure out how to import data while using the stored procedure to create the ID. this ID is not in the source data, it should be created as you add rows

Comment: There are many, many ways to do that.  We'd need to know more about your specific requirements and the particular challenge you're facing -right now it's a bit too general and broad.

Comment: Have you tried placing the ID-generation logic into a UDF, which is easier to get a scalar return value from than a stored procedure?

Comment: I can't modify the table structure  in any way. I have a record set that needs to be imported. Usually this task is done trough the software that uses the DB, but this is a very large record set and the software in question can't handle that much data. Usually the program runs the stored proc to create the ID when a user creates an entry.